# Formulas not calculated when exporting as csv

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I have this Excel file (`.xlsx`):

```
+---+-------+
|   |   A   |
+---+-------+
| 1 | 1     |
| 2 | =A1+1 |
| 3 | =2*3  |
+---+-------+
```

In Laravel I have configured this code to display the contents

```
return Excel::load(base_path() . '/test.xlsx')->string('csv');
```

which returns the text of the cells: `"1","=A1+1","=3*2"`

What I want is the calculated values, but with the same formatting: `"1","2","6"`

The code

```
return Excel::load(base_path() . '/test.xlsx')->get();
```

returns the correct calculated data, but in the wrong format.

Comment: PHP is not a spreadsheet, it has no idea what =A1+1 means in the context of a spreadsheet and will just export the raw value of the column.  You'd need to implement this functionality yourself (build an array of columns and rows, scan the first character for any cell for the = symbol, if you find an = symbol, assume the rest of the column is a formula and try to execute it)

Comment: That's not a PHP function, it's a function of whatever library you're using to parse the file.  If you don't like the formatting provided by get, you can extend the class that implements it and replace the superclass implementation with your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an option precisely for that purpose. You probably have a config file at `config/excel.php` (if not just do `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"` ). Take a look at the `export` array, which holds the following option:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pre-calculate formulas during export
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'calculate'                   => false,
```

Set it to true and there you have it.